# Reduced major axis line and CI for ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there anyway to add a reduced major axis line (and ideally CI) to a ggplot? I know I can use method="lm" to get an OLS fit, but there doesn't seem to be a default method for RMA. I can get the RMA coefs and the CI interval from package lmodel2, but adding them with geom_abline() doesn't seem to work. Here's dummy data and code. I just want to replace the OLS line and CI with a RMA line and CI:

```
dat <- data.frame(a=log10(rnorm(50, 30, 10)), b=log10(rnorm(50, 20, 2)))

ggplot(dat, aes(x=a, y=b) ) + 
    geom_point(shape=1) +       
    geom_smooth(method="lm")
```

Edit1: the code below gets the RMA (here called SMA - standardized major axis) coefs and CIs. Package lmodel2 provides more detailed output, while package smatr returns just the coefs and CIs, if that's any help:

```
library(lmodel2)
fit1 <- lmodel2(b ~ a, data=dat)

library(smatr)
fit2 <- line.cis(b, a, data=dat)
```

Comment: please add the code for `lmodel2()` that you are using.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Chase commented, the actual `lmodel2()` code and the `ggplot` code you are using would be helpful. But here's an example that may point you in the right direction:

```
dat <- data.frame(a=log10(rnorm(50, 30, 10)), b=log10(rnorm(50, 20, 2)))
mod <- lmodel2(a ~ b, data=dat,"interval", "interval", 99)

#EDIT: mod is a list, with components (data.frames) regression.results and 
#        confidence.intervals containing the intercepts+slopes for different 
#        estimation methods; just put the right values into geom_abline
ggplot(dat,aes(x=b,y=a)) + geom_point() + 
   geom_abline(intercept=mod$regression.results[4,2],
            slope=mod$regression.results[4,3],colour="blue") + 
   geom_abline(intercept=mod$confidence.intervals[4,2],
            slope=mod$confidence.intervals[4,4],colour="red") + 
   geom_abline(intercept=mod$confidence.intervals[4,3],
            slope=mod$confidence.intervals[4,5],colour="red") + 
   xlim(c(-10,10)) + ylim(c(-10,10))
```

Full disclosure: I know nothing about RMA regression, so I just plucked out the relevent slopes and intercepts and plopped them into `geom_abline()`, using some example code from `lmodel2` as a guide. The CIs produced in this toy example don't seem to make much sense, since I had to force ggplot to zoom out using `xlim()` and `ylim()` in order to see the CI lines (red).

But maybe this will help you construct a working example in `ggplot()`.

EDIT2: With OPs added code to extract the coefficients, the `ggplot()` would be something like this:

```
ggplot(dat,aes(x=b,y=a)) + geom_point() + 
geom_abline(intercept=fit2[1,1],slope=fit2[2,1],colour="blue") + 
geom_abline(intercept=fit2[1,2],slope=fit2[2,2],colour="red") + 
geom_abline(intercept=fit2[1,3],slope=fit2[2,3],colour="red")
```

Comment: Exactly what I was going to write up, +1. The thing to note here is that `lmodel2()` returns a list, and the `regression.results` are a data.frame which are part of that list. From there, it's just a matter of specifying what you want to extract from that data.frame.

Comment: @Chase - Edited to include your points, thanks. Annoyingly, the regression.results data.frame has some strange colnames, presumably for visual effect. The "Slope" column is really "    Slope". That tripped me up briefly, and is why I ended up using "[".

Comment: Thanks, this works well for the actual line, though any ideas why the CIs are so weird? Also, in this package RMA=ranged major axis and SMA=reduced(standardized) major axis, so the row numbers would be 3 rather than 4. The smatr package, which i gave code for in an edit to my question, actually makes it easier to get the coefs.

Comment: never mind - once I corrected the row numbers to be 3, the CIs worked fine, thanks a lot.

Comment: @Steve - Haven't the foggiest notion; don't know much about this type of regression. That might be a better question for stats.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 8):

Building off Joran's answer, I think it's a little easier to pass the whole data frame to `geom_abline`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(lmodel2)

dat <- data.frame(a=log10(rnorm(50, 30, 10)), b=log10(rnorm(50, 20, 2)))
mod <- lmodel2(a ~ b, data=dat,"interval", "interval", 99)

reg <- mod$regression.results
names(reg) <- c("method", "intercept", "slope", "angle", "p-value")

ggplot(dat) + 
  geom_point(aes(b, a)) +
  geom_abline(data = reg, aes(intercept = intercept, slope = slope, colour = method))
```

Answer (score 0):

I found myself in the same situation.

1. Obtain fitted values and their confidence intervals using the `ggpmisc` package:
   `cibrary(ggpmisc)`
   `ci <- predict.lmodel2(fit1, method= 'RMA', interval= "confidence")`
2. Add the model predictions to your data:
   `datci <- cbind(dat, ci)`
3. Plot using `geom_smooth` arguments like transparency and line width (of course, you can customize them)
   `p <- ggplot(datci, aes(x= b, y= a)) + geom_point() + geom_line(aes(x= b, y= a)), lwd= 1.1, alpha= 0.6)`
4. Use `geom_ribbon` if you want to add confidence intervals:
   `p + geom_ribbon(aes(ymin= lwr, ymax= upr, fill= feather), alpha= 0.3, color= NA)`